# How to disconnect a bluetooth connection via MAC address on Android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I used the following code, although all the steps are gone when debugging, but I can't disconnect the Bluetooth connection.

```
/**
 * Disconnect
 *
 * @param address Mac Address
 */
public void disConnectDevice(String address) {
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        gatt.close();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Disconnect
 *
 * @param address Mac Address
 */
public void disConnectDevice(String address) {
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect(); // Don't do this. Delete this line.
}

private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        gatt.disconnect(); // add code.
        gatt.close();
    }
};
```